# Let $G$ be a finite group with $[G:Z(G)]=n$. Show that the number of elements in each conjugacy class of $G$ is a divisor of $n$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, automorphism-group

> Let $G$ be a finite group with $[G:Z(G)]=n$. Show that the number of elements in each conjugacy class of $G$ is a divisor of $n$.

I've spent a couple hours trying to answer this and my answer seems hazy and bloated because of this. I'm convinced there is a much simpler and more elegant solution.

Here's my attempt:

$$ [G:Z(G)]=n~~ \text{iff}~~ \frac{|G|}{|Z(G)|}=n \rightarrow |G|=|Z(G)|\cdot n $$

We know $[G:C_G(x)]$ is equal to the number of elements in each distinct conjugacy class of $G$. But if we consider the orbits ${\rm orb}(x)$ for $\forall x \in G$ when $G$ acts on itself by conjugation (i.e. $\phi(x)=i_a(x)$ for $\forall i_a \in{\rm Inn}(G)$), then these elements are exactly the same as the elements in the distinct conjugacy classes; so it follows then that ${\rm stab}(x)=C_G(x)$.
$$ |{\rm stab}(x)|=|C_G(x)|~~\text{and}~~ |{\rm orb}(x)|=[G:C_G(x)]$$
Now: $$|Z(G)|=\left|\bigcap_{x\in G}C_G(x)\right|=\left|\bigcap_{x\in G}{\rm stab}(x)\right|\rightarrow \left|\bigcap_{x\in G}{\rm stab}(x)\right|\cdot n = |G|$$
So:
$$ 
n=\prod_{x\in G} |{\rm orb}(x)|\equiv \prod_{x\in G} [G:C_G(x)]
$$
then
$[G:C_G(x)]$ (which as stated above is equal to the number of elements in each distinct conjugacy class) divides $n$.

Any help or suggestions on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The point is that $Z(G) \le C_G(x)$ for all $x \in G$, so $|G:C_G(x)|$ divides $|G:Z(G)|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property of subgroups is that for $H,K \leq G$ and $H\subseteq K$, then:
$$
|G|=[G:K]\cdot[K:H]\cdot|H|
$$

Since $Z(G)\subsetneq C_G(x)$ in general, then:
$$
|G|=[G:C_G(x)]\cdot[C_G(x):Z(G)]\cdot|Z(G)|
$$
So $n=[G:C_G(x)]\cdot[C_G(x):Z(G)]$ and therefore $[G:C_G(x)]$ divides $n$.